# H2o in R Connection reset by peer

Tags: r, database-connection, h2o, lasso-regression

I am running `h2o` in `R` using `h2o.glm()`.

For some reason I keep getting this error:

```
CURL ERROR: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I varied the size of my cluster and dataset and yet the connection seems to break.

Does anybody know how to solve this I am running out of ideas!

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: When you start h2o with h2o.init() it mentions a couple of log files to look at.  Look at them for clues.

Comment: I tried but the file they reported is created isn't there

Comment: That is probably because the R session ended.  Try again.

Comment: Yes you were right about that I have the file now. No error is given it just stops while the results are coming in. Nothing is reported in the fatal.log and .err files. The .out file does contains results but no error statements.

Comment: Can you describe more about your cluster, and your client in relation to that? E.g. are client and cluster on the same machine, and the cluster only has that single node? Or something more complicated? Which OS?

Comment: I am working on a linux OS cluster and assigned JAVA to have a massive memory. I created an H2o cluster of 300G using a single node but I also tried multiple nodes no success. It feels more like a time based issue but no clue why.